Hashicorp packer version upgrade to latest 1.11.2 from 1.8.0
While upgrading packer version getting below error:
Error: Failed to initialize build "amazon-ebs" The builder amazon-ebs is unknown by Packer, and is likely part of a plugin that is not installed.
You may find the needed plugin along with installation instructions documented 904on the Packer integrations page.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations?filter=amazon
[Container] 2024/11/19 17:19:12.070019 Command did not exit successfully cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/build_config/packer/deployami/ && packer validate ./packer.json exit status 1
[Container] 2024/11/19 17:19:12.074475 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/11/19 17:19:12.074503 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/build_config/packer/deployami/ && packer validate ./packer.json. Reason: exit status 1
https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/integrations/hashicorp/amazon
Tried to upgrade amazon plugin:
packer plugins install github.com/hashicorp/amazon
This time throws some Ansible error:
amazon-ebs: TASK [aws-gather-facts-ec2 : Get EC2 tag value for Name] ***********************
amazon-ebs: task path: /etc/ansible/application/roles/aws-gather-facts-ec2/tasks/main.yml:43
amazon-ebs: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
amazon-ebs: "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'Name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/application/roles/aws-gather-facts-ec2/tasks/main.yml': line 43, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Get EC2 tag value for Name\n ^ here\n" amazon-ebs: }

name: Get EC2 tag value for Name
set_fact:
ec2_instance_tag_name: "{{ ec2_tags.tags.Name }}"
tags:

always
base



Any suggestion would be appreciated ?

You already solved the first error by installing the EBS builder plugin (packer init is preferred for future notice) and can remove it from the question. The second error is unrelated to the first, and possibly unrelated to Packer, but we need a MCVE to determine more.
